# Buscar un valor <= en un rango limitado en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Dentro de SQL, estoy buscando encontrar un valor no específicamente determinado (volumen) dentro de una tabla como uno de dos condicionales (el otro son valores fijos, kilometraje, que no tengo porque buscar en un rango) para encontrar un tercer valor dentro de la misma tabla (precio).

Mi tabla dummy de ejemplo es:

| volumen | kilometraje | precio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 130 | 400 | 100 |
| 140 | 400 | 200 |
| 150 | 400 | 300 |

He estado utilizando esta línea de código

```
    SELECT precio FROM ebPrecios WHERE volumen <= ? AND kms <= ? ORDER BY precio DESC LIMIT 1
```

y al momento de reemplazar con valores como 137 o 145 o 150 me regresa los valores adecuados de la tabla de precio, pero necesito limitar para que no me regrese un valor si es mayor a 150, que es mi límite máximo que puedo tener de volumen.

Por ejemplo, que no me regrese 300 cuando le doy un volumen de 180, si no que me diga que no encontró ningún valor

¿Hay alguna manera, sencilla o no, de hacer esto?

Comment: ¿la tabla ebPrecios tiene ID y es autoincremental?

Comment: no, solo contiene esos valores pero supongo que se lo puedo agregar, ¿eso ayudaría?

Comment: no estaba pensando hacer un **having** pero creo que no es necesario

Comment: y si intentas `SELECT IF(precio<= 150,precio,"NO HAY VALOR") FROM ebPrecios WHERE volumen <= ? AND kms <= ? ORDER BY precio DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: ya le agregué en la función que construye la query, que si me pasa un parámetro mayor a 150 no haga la query y me regrese un valor que sirve de notificación, 

se que no lo resuelve desde sql pero resuelve el problema al final del dia

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se puede hacer es colocar una condición para cambiar el valor de precio a "NO HAY VALOR" si este es mayor a 150 de esta forma:

```
SELECT IF(precio<=150,precio,"NO HAY VALOR") FROM ebPrecios WHERE volumen <= ? AND kms <= ? ORDER BY precio DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: como el precio no varia cuando va a mas de 150 de volumen me sigue pasando el valor, pero voy a intentar asignar una fila mas con un precio superior si pasa el volumen y con eso creo que este método funcionaria bien. Nada mas que contesto mas al rato porque necesito dormir un rato. Gracias!

Comment: @JulioC con un precio de 150 la condición es verdadera porque 150 <= 150 por este motivo te va a seguir arrojando el valor

Comment: mm no, y la verdad no se bien que esta pasando, no entiendo mucho de sql, pero ya le agregué en la función que construye la query, que si me pasa un parámetro mayor a 150 no haga la query y me regrese un valor que sirve de notificación, chance cuando tenga el cerebro menos frito y este mas descansado pueda regresar a revisar esto.